# Entering a password via the console

Tags: python

i would like someone to make a program that asks the user to enter a password and when the user enters the password in the password field the password is not shown in text nor figures.
just like the linux kernel.( when you type sudo bash or sudo su )

Comment: searched `password library in python`on google, and the first result was `getpass — Portable password input — Python v2.7.3`

Answer (score 6):

See

http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html

```
import getpass
passwd = getpass.getpass()
```

Comment: +1, I never knew about this library.